# I am not sure why my else if is not being called in my IBAction

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have created an `IBAction` that handles 2 buttons, first one's title is "True" and the second one's title is "False", when tapped they should display a label however the else if never gets called.

```
@IBAction func trueOrFalse(sender: UIButton) {
      if sender.currentTitle == "True" {
             answerR.hidden = false
             answerW.hidden = true
      } else if sender.currentTitle == "False" {
                    print("hi")
             answerW.hidden = false
             answerR.hidden = true
      }
 }
```

`answerW` and `answerR` are the labels.
I am not sure why, I have tried a couple of things like using taps but I can not seem to figure it out.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the IBAction and print out what `sender.currentTitle` actually is when you press it.

Comment: I have just implemented your code and it works fine. are you sure the IBAction is hooked up to both buttons w/ Touch Up Inside?

Comment: why not to to create separated IBActions for each button?

Comment: It's also a little easier to give each button a different tag (0 and 1, for example), and check for that instead of checking for the title.

Comment: Yeah so I guess somewhere along the way I might have gotten rid of the TouchUpInside.... Im new at this, thanks for the help! @BJHStudios

Comment: cool, I will make it an answer for you to accept!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like one of your buttons isn't registering the IBAction - double check and make sure each are connected via Touch Up Inside. If they are connected w/ a different method it may not register as you expect!

Answer (score 0):

You should use button tags. It is very simple like below:

Firstly, you should set each button tag like below:

Buton1 Tag = 0
Buton2 Tag = 1

[image]

Then use below code:

```
@IBAction func trueOrFalse(sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.tag == 0 {
            answerR.hidden = false
            answerW.hidden = true
        }else
        {
            print("hi")
            answerW.hidden = false
            answerR.hidden = true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

you need to eliminate optional that comes with string

```
@IBAction func trueOrFalse(sender: UIButton) {
      if (sender.currentTitle!)! == "True" {
             answerR.hidden = false
             answerW.hidden = true
      } else if (sender.currentTitle!)! == "False" {
                    print("hi")
             answerW.hidden = false
             answerR.hidden = true
      }
 }
```

Comment: you can still do a boolean test with an optional